# Pandas dataframe returned differently when using flask app

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am writing a flask app do host some code I've written for stock analysis, the code works fine when run on its own, but when used in the flask app it returns an error and this seems to be because it receives the dataframe slightly differently so the key I'm looking for is no longer present.

Usually, I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
0                                       Total Revenue  138699000  125843000  110360000  89950000 
1                                     Cost of Revenue   44151000   42910000  38353000  34261000
2                                        Gross Profit   94548000   82933000  72007000  55689000 
3                                   Operating Expense   42591000   39974000  36949000  33057000
4                                    Operating Income   51957000   42959000  35058000  22632000
5           Net Non Operating Interest Income Expense   -2574000   -2686000  -2733000  -2222000
6                                Other Income Expense    2827000    3415000  4149000   2739000
```

where I can then use:

```
net_income = income_statement[income_statement['Breakdown']=='Net Income Common Stockholders'].iloc[0,2:]
```

But instead, in the logs, flask is receiving a dataframe that looks like:

```
endDate                              2019-06-30    2018-06-30   2017-06-30   2016-06-30
Breakdown                                                                              
costOfRevenue                       42910000000   38353000000  34261000000  32780000000
discontinuedOperations                     None          None         None         None
ebit                                42959000000   35058000000  29331000000  27188000000
effectOfAccountingCharges                  None          None         None         None
extraordinaryItems                         None          None         None         None
grossProfit                         82933000000   72007000000  62310000000  58374000000
incomeBeforeTax                     43688000000   36474000000  29901000000  25639000000
incomeTaxExpense                     4448000000   19903000000   4412000000   5100000000
interestExpense                     -2686000000   -2733000000  -2222000000  -1243000000
```

Note, I've shortened the tables so the rows are different, but why is "Breakdown" now in the index rather than than a column?

Comment: What are the column headers for your dataframe?

Comment: Hi, usually they are: 
`Index, Breakdown, ttm, 2019-06-30, 2018-06-30, 2017-06-30, 2016-06-30`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was due to having a different version of the yahoo_fin package in my Spyder IDE and what my local pc was using with Flask.